# Windows 10 Command Prompt "start" command no longer working

Tags: command-prompt

For a few years (obviously the PS version would change) I would call the following:

`start "" "c:\program files\adobe\adobe photoshop cc 2018\photoshop.exe" /b`

and that would launch Photoshop from the command prompt. Now I'm receiving the error 'The parameter is incorrect'

[image: Image of error window]

and 'Access is denied' within the command prompt. I'm running Windows 10 (build 17682.rs_prerelease.180525.1616).

I've tried running the same command as Administrator and I've also rebooted into Safe Mode to run the command. No luck.

Comment: Does it work for other executables?

Comment: What happens if you leave the `/b` off the end?

Comment: 'start' will work for some applications but not for others. For instance iexplore.exe throws the error but something like mousekeyboardcenter.exe runs correctly. All executable files I've tried are in c:\program files

Comment: Leaving the /b off the end still throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that adding /MAX as the 1st parameter resolved the issue for an exe I'm calling.  For a url, I had to switch my default browser to Edge to get that to work.

Comment: `/MAX` did it! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
start /b /w /D "c:\program files\adobe\adobe photoshop cc 2018" photoshop.exe
```

Comment: That won't work. The first quoted parameter is assumed to be the windows title. See [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)